# How to show the series of expectations for truncated symmetric random variables is convergent

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Suppose that $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. with symmetric distribution and that $E(|X_1|)<\infty$.

I want to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1iE(X_i 1_{[|X_i|<i]}) $ converges.

Attempt: Since $E|X_i|$ is finite, we have $|X_n /n| \to 0 $ almost surely.
But I couldn't figure out a convergence test to show the series converges.

Comment: If the distribution of every $X_i$ is symmetric then $E(X_i:|X_i|<i)=0$ for every $i$, no? (And the i.i.d. and integrability conditions are not required.)

Comment: @Did I think that is true only for symmetry about 0. I mean, Normal(5,1) is also symmetric but that expectation is not 0. Correct me please.

Comment: Yes I thought you were talking about symmetry about zero.